# Exception in thread "main" org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I am trying a simple zookeeper example for `Leader` election, and I always get an error and the server doesn't start up. This is my code:

```
public LeaderElection() throws IOException, InterruptedException, KeeperException {
    setZk(new ZooKeeper("localhost", TIMEOUT, this));

    /* This call gives the problem */
    Stat s = getZk().exists(MASTER, this);

    if (s == null) {
        getZk().create(MASTER, "This node is used for election.".getBytes(),
                ZooDefs.Ids.OPEN_ACL_UNSAFE, CreateMode.PERSISTENT);
    }
    //wait till SyncConnected Signal is received in process method.
    latch.await();

    setNodePath(getZk().create(MASTER + NODE, null /*no data yet*/,
            ZooDefs.Ids.OPEN_ACL_UNSAFE, CreateMode.EPHEMERAL_SEQUENTIAL));
}
```

At the `exists()` call I get the error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for

Please let me know what am I missing. I am using version 3.4.5 of zk, and a time out of 15K.

Comment: Can you post anything interesting from the log on the zookeeper servers themselves?  Can you verify that the the zk cluster is in fact up?